# why this code on error still con.commit()

Tags: java, jdbc

I have set the `stdImage` to not null in database, when i don't insert the image it throws an error but still con.commit() work out and data instead of rollback() save to database without image can someone solve the logical error in this code please. Actually rollback() is not working. I will be thankful.

```
public void stdSave(String stdID, String stdName, String fName, String sSec, String contactNo, Date bdate, String address, byte[] image) throws RemoteException, SQLException {

    String stdQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.StudentTable (stID, stName, stFName, classSection,"
                    + "contact, date, pAddress) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            String imgQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.StdImage (stdID, stdImage) VALUES (?, ?)";
            Savepoint save = null;

            try { 
            try(PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(stdQuery); 
                    PreparedStatement stmt1 = con.prepareStatement(imgQuery)) {
                con.setAutoCommit(false);
                save = con.setSavepoint();
                stmt.setString(1, stdID);
                stmt.setString(2, stdName);
                stmt.setString(3, fName);
                stmt.setString(4, sSec);
                stmt.setString(5, contactNo);
                stmt.setDate(6, bdate);
                stmt.setString(7, address);
                stmt.execute();

                stmt1.setString(1, stdID);
                stmt1.setBytes(2, image);
                stmt1.execute();

            }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                try {
                    con.rollback(save);
                }
                catch (Exception e1) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Cannot add the student to database " + e);
                }
            }
            con.commit();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `con.commit();` after the try-catch block, and since your catch all the exceptions, you always calls commit.

You should probably move the `commit` inside the try block:

```
        ...
        con.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        try {
            con.rollback(save);
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Cannot add the student to database " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i do it but still after exception thrown for null image i am unable to add stdImage to database i don't understand why. you can see i have setAutoCommit() to false but still

Comment: @user8297824 you call `con.commit()` even when an exception occurs. You shouldn't.

Comment: i had put con.commit() in try block but its not working after i try to save the data with null image and then try to save it with image, in table it didn't save the image on second attempt in database

Comment: @user8297824 Are you saying you want to recover from the case where you inserted just the StudentTable row without the corresponding StdImage row? Assuming stID is the primary key of these tables, you can't INSERT into StudentTable a stID that's already there. You'll have to check if the stID is already present in that table (with a SELECT statement), and only if not, call INSERT.

Comment: yes that's what i am saying when i inserted data in StudentTable without stdImage it gives me a null exception for image and then i add the image to to same it didn't give any error that primary key already used but didn't add image to the stdImage table so how to recover from this null exception of stdImage and insert the stdImage to the stdImage Table

Answer (score 0):

Never do `con.commit()` in catch block, this can lead to unintended commits. Move `con.commit()` to your try block. 
Next, please see that you are doing rollback to a savepoint, but savepoint is null. It is not initialzed.
`con.rollback(save);` is done but here `save=null`.

Either simply do `con.rollback()` or initialialize the savepoint and then rollback upto it.